# Json convert to object error when deserialize object

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I convert json to object and get this error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "{"mid":"2","phone":"0965403801","requestId":"1585970510.732827","bankHubToken":"eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOiIxNjMzNDE4NzgyNzQ0IiwidG9rZW4iOiI5NWJmYWM3OC00YmY3LTQyM2MtYjAxNS00NTNjMjkzYzk1ZWEiLCJzaWduIjoiLzVrcTg2dWdReFUvQ1daWCt2TERSaGhvaXN1VC9hS1JpejEwUGtTU0dxUVx1MDAzZCJ9","userName":"1392H46"}" to type 'OBBE.DGBIZ.API.Model.DataFieldUploadFile'. Path '', line 1, position 305.'
```

my code

```
var data = context.ActionArguments["data"];

if (data == null)
{
  context.Result = new OkObjectResult(

    new ErrorResponseMessage() { context = new ContextResponse(false, new List<string>() { APPID, HANDER_ERRORCODE.ERR_REQUEST_CONTENT.ToString(), "Request null" }, new ContextRequest("", ""), ResultConstants.ERROR_CODE_FAIL, "Request null") });

  return;
}

try
{
  String x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

  data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataFieldUploadFile>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
}
```

and my class

```
public class DataFieldUploadFile
{
  public String? mid { get; set; }
  public String? requestId { get; set; }
  public String? phone { get; set; }
  public String? bankHubToken { get; set; }
  public String? userName { get; set; }
}
```

I try but not OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
DataFieldUploadFile data = context.ActionArguments["data"] as DataFieldUploadFile;
```

if data is null it means that data is a probably a json string already, and try to double serialize it.

So you really need this code

```
string json = context.ActionArguments["data"]?.ToString();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
{
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataFieldUploadFile>(json);
}
else ... you another code
```

Comment: data is a string guy

Comment: @VuSon this is what I was thinking about too. See my updated answer

Comment: oh, it was okay, can u tell me why a json string can not use SerializeObject , cause it has return a tring too

Comment: @VuSon Because it was serialized already and your try to serialize data twice.  Then you will need  to deserialize it twice to get some data. At first deserialize to get a  valid json , after this to get a class instance. Nobody needs it for any reason.